# WebdriverManager throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli in Selenium 4.0

Tags: maven, webdriver, webdriver-manager

When chrome driver initialised, with selenium 4.0 and webdriver manager maven dependency 4.2.0

It throws

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli

Causing

> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new
> session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or
> browser start-up failure.

As a result, even though browser window is launched , session is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to MAVEN dependency conflicts to solve this added below dependency and worked successfully.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.69.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The discussion-
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9913